# HTML table row with extra full-width column

Tags: css, html, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an HTML table with many rows and several columns. I want to append a `td` to some of these rows such that the `td` would look like a new row and span the entire width of the table. This is useful to keep all of the data for a single table row under the same `tr` tag and would allow me to show extra data that relates to that same row but that won't fit in a single table column, like long-form notes. For example:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>Third</td>
      <td class="magic" colspan="3">
        This is long-form data that should look like a full-width
        row without creating an extra tr tag to hold it.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that the same table also uses jquery-ui's `sortable` api to allow the rows to be drag/dropped in order to sort them. Also, the end result is then printed.

How do I do this without messing up my markup with illegal divs or abandoning html tables altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS `flexbox` property to achieve what you are trying, use a class selector for the specific row you want to span the width.

`Flexbox` has a property `flex-direction` which let's define the flow of the children of a component to either `column` or `row`

Example: [Link to a codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrGKKo)

PS: I have not tested it on a jQuery UI.

Comment: I'm definitely starting to think that using divs with `Flexbox` instead of old-style table markup is the way to go on this one.

Comment: `Flexbox` gives a wide array of properties to use for display so yeah it still would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `colspan` attribute for this:

```
<tr>
  <th colspan="5">Full-Width Row</th>
</tr>
```

Replace the 5 with the number of columns in the table. I haven't confirmed this works with jQuery UI, but it's pretty quick to test it out.

Comment: Clarified my question some with example markup. The goal is to show the regular data for the row in normal columns, followed by an additional column (or perhaps some other markup) that appears as a new row without creating an extra tr tag. An extra tr tag would make it difficult to keep the two rows together when sorting.